# another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a mysql server running on linux system. i'm already running one c++ prog which is building up the data base with current date and time stamp. I'm trying to run another process in c++ which is accessing different db but i'm having error.

error is as below:

```
InnoDB: check that you do not have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files
InnoDB: Unable to lock /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1, error: 11
```

please can somebody explain whats going wrong in here

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/external-locking.html

Talks about "external locking" which can be turned on or off for MyISAM databases to support multiple servers on one set of data.  It does not seem to apply to InnoDB however.  And this page:
http://book.opensourceproject.org.cn/lamp/mysql/mysql5cert/opensource/0672328127/ch42lev1sec1.html

Says it's not possible with InnoDB because it can only be done on read-only filesystems, and InnoDB does not work on those.

So it seems the answer is that you cannot do it, for two reasons: first because you are still populating the DB while also wanting to read it, and second because you are using InnoDB rather than MyISAM.

Comment: zwinck thanks made my understanding about mysql bit more clear.

Answer (score 4):

I was solved this problem by kill mysqld process

### To kill all mysqld process **on Linux** :

```
# killall mysqld mysqld_safe
```

---

Wait for 10 seconds atleast so that it shut down cleanly.

### Now, run this command to check whether still there are some mysqld process remained or not ?

```
# ps aux | grep mysqld
```

---

### If you still able to see more than run this command :

```
killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe
```

---

This will kill all mysqld processes.

Comment: Thanks @AnasSafi. I tried your solution on my MAMP PRO on macOS and it works well.

Comment: Works! used MAMP Pro on MacOS